# create an Average column from a sum and a count in spotfire

Tags: sql, average, spotfire

I retrieve data from database and the sum and the count are automatically calculated.

Something like

```
Select Data, Product, count(*) as Num, sum(cost) as cost
from myTable
group by Data, Product
```

From these data directly inputed in Spotfire, I would like to display by date the total cost, and also the average cost.
I cannot use the AVG aggregation directly, so I was thinking about using a formula like `cost*Num/sum(num)`  but it is not displaying the right number as sum(num) is not per day...

Is there a way to specify in spotfire formula to sum only per day ?
Or another way to do that ?

---

EDIT :
Here are some data

```
2015/7/1    BIKE    128 3,635,770
2015/7/1    AUTO    487 22,932,530
2015/7/2    AUTO    519 25,219,780
2015/7/2    BIKE    123 3,355,270
2015/7/3    BIKE    135 4,191,060
2015/7/3    AUTO    507 24,687,420
```

For example, if you use avg on Cost in 2015/7/1, you'll have 13,284,150 (`=(3,635,770 + 22,932,530) / 2`)
But the real average is 18,916,294 (avg on 2015/7/1 independant of product, `=(3,635,770 * 128 + 22,932,530 * 487) / (128+487)`)

Comment: What is the datatype of Date?

Comment: date is a date ;) only the day date, no timestamp

Comment: Please show some data.

Comment: @SNC added, is that enough ?

Comment: Yes that's enough. You can use Group By clause with date column

Comment: @SNC group by clause in spotfire ? how can I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula you can use depends a bit on which visualization you are using. If, for example, you use a bar chart, you can use the formula `Sum([Num] * [Cost]) / Sum([Num])`. But you need to add this as custom expression, not insert calculated column. In the bar chart example, you then have date on the category axis.

I tested the `Sum([Num] * [Cost]) / Sum([Num])` formula and it works in most visualizations, e.g. cross table, heat map, bar chart, line chart, etc.
But not in the table visualization, because this doesn't aggregate to higher levels.